# Extending SyndicationItem existing elements

Tags: c#, syndication-feed

SyndicationItem has Authors element of SyndicationPerson. How can I extend SyndicationPerson such that it has Id attribute. Which is the author id.

Comment: I don't think there is an author id in RSS specs

Comment: I meant using element extension or attribute extension

Comment: Yes but I mean if it's not in the specs, clients wouldn't be able be use that field anyway.

Comment: not sure if I understand, I'm authoring the client as well. I am able to use element extension to add AuthorId in c# however I would like to extend existing SyndicationPerson to add AuthorId there.